# How do I process signals in main thread with mutex locked?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11, mutex

I am writing a multi-threaded Qt Application but because of OpenGL related calls, some part of the code has to be always executed in the main thread.

Rough code to simulate the problem will be:

```
QMutex mutex;

void openGLCalls()
{
}
void foo1()
{
    mutex.lock();
    openGLCalls();
    mutex.unlock();

}

class CBHandler : public QObject
{

public:
    CBHandler(QObject *parent = NULL)
    {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(requestCallbackExec()), SLOT(runCallback()),    Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);

    }

    static CBHandler *Instance();

    public slots:

    void runCallback  ()
    {
        //in the main thread as object lies there
        openGLCalls();
    }

signals:
    void requestCallbackExec ();

};

class Thread1
{
    void run()
    {
        while(1)
        {
            mutex.lock();
            CBHandler::Instance()->emit requestCallbackExec();
            mutex.unlock();
        }
    }
};

void main()
{

    Thread1 thread;
    CBHandler cbhandler;
    thread.start();
    while(1)
    {
        if(/*some key pressed*/)
        {
            foo1();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code ensures that "openGLCalls()" is always executed in the main thread.
But problem is, if the mutex is locked by Thread1 and the main thread tries to call foo1 then main thread sleeps when trying to lock the mutex.
And since main thread is sleeping, mutex locked by Thread1 never gets unlocked because of 'requestCallbackExec' signal never getting processed.

Comment: What exactly is your mutex protecting?

Comment: '//do something'. mutex makes sure that //do something is either executed by main thread or worker thread

Comment: I replaced //do something with 'openGLCalls()' but its not exactly one function. Main thread may do something which can change data and worker thread may want to read that via some other code.

Comment: This does not compute. The worker thread (1) requests a callback to be initiated and (2) reads shared data. The second thing needs to be protected by a mutex. But why would you protect the first?

Comment: Note that the documentation for the [`connect overload`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-2) you are using states that the receiver context is implicitly `this` so the slot is invoked on the same thread as that from which the signal was emitted.  Further, the documentation for [`Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) states `"This connection [type] must not be used if the receiver lives in the signalling thread, or else the application will deadlock"` so the code as shown is not valid from a `Qt` perspective.

Comment: Slot executes on the thread where receiver object lies which in this case is main thread. Signal is emitted from worker thread so its perfectly valid.

Comment: Also, what mutex is protecting or why it is protecting is not the question I asked.

Comment: Your `foo1()` could `tryLock()` the mutex and return on fail

Comment: What mutex is protecting or why it is protecting is a question you need to *answer*. You are simply using the mutex wrong. There is no need to lock it around requestCallbackExec. Why are you doing this?

Comment: I think, it is not needed to lock a simple function, because the function will be copied for each thread. In other word, in your sketch of the code, mutex is redundant, Just remove the locks.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the event loop spin while `.lock()` is waiting. There seems to be no method to do it. So you could busy wait:

```
while(!mutex.tryLock()) {
    QEventLoop loop;
    loop.processEvents();
}
```

You could add a timeout to the `.tryLock()` call to not heat CPU but it would cost you some latency.

Comment: This solves the problem but since i am new to stackoverflow my vote didn't count.

Comment: However I found a better solution myself. if anybody else is interested, I used QWaitCondition along with QCoreApplication::postEvent(). Of course receiver and event has to be your own defined so that you can call 'QWaitCondition::wakeOne()'